# How to convert Regular Date to unixtime in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, unix-timestamp

How can i convert date which looks like this 12092008 to unixtime like this 1221215809

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use the following:

```
function covertToUnixTime(yourDate) {
    return new Date(yourDate.substring(4, 8) + '/' + 
                    yourDate.substring(2, 4) + '/' + 
                    yourDate.substring(0, 2)).getTime() / 1000;
}

covertToUnixTime('12092008');   // Returns: 1221170400
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery datepicker's [utility](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) functions, parseDate and formatDate.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
var day = $("#day").val();
var month   = $("#month").val();
var year    = $("#year").val();
var date    = new Date();
date.setFullYear(year, month, day)
var unixtimeMS = date.getTime();
var unixtime = parseInt(unixtimeMS / 1000);
alert(unixtime);
```

Comment: You need to be very careful with this - remember that the clocks on your clients' computers may not be set to the same time zone as your servers.