# Determining if shown dates in a table are before today's date using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for help to accomplish this seemingly simple task. I just don't have the know-how to figure this out.

Basically, I have a form that I select a date (for the due date) for a work order from jQuery's datepicker. The results are displayed on a separate page in a table with other work orders.

I am trying to figure out how to determine if the shown date in the table is past due or not and change the CSS if the date is before today's date. Because there are several rows in the table and each row has a due date that needs to be evaluated, this has stumped me.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="dueDate">November 1, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="dueDate">November 4, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="dueDate">November 26, 2012</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the layout of the table when the form is displayed. And this is the closest that I can think to put together to determine if the date displayed is before today's date or not.

```
$('.dueDate').each(function(){
var dueDate = $(this).val();
var today = new Date();
if (Date.parse(dueDate) < Date.parse(today)){
$(".dueDate").addClass("pastDue");
}        
});
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Date.parse`

```
  if (Date.parse(dueDate) < Date.parse(today)) {
      $(".dueDate").addClass("pastDue");// . for class
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it in the code, but it still isn't working. Did I implement it correctly? I've updated that code to show what I'm trying.

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to use the selector `.dueDate` not `#dueDate`  this is because dueDate is a class, not an ID

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to convert the dates to Unix timestamp, so it's just a number. Then you would be just comparing numbers and by doing that you would know if the date is past or not. You can use this function which I got from here: [How to convert Regular Date to unixtime in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295939/how-to-convert-regular-date-to-unixtime-in-javascript)

```
function covertToUnixTime(yourDate) {
    return new Date(yourDate.substring(4, 8) + '/' + 
                    yourDate.substring(2, 4) + '/' + 
                    yourDate.substring(0, 2)).getTime() / 1000;
}

covertToUnixTime('12092008');   // Returns: 1221170400
//12-09-2008 is the date
```

You could also use `jQuery.now()` to get the actual date in a timestamp and then compare between both too, for more about it, check here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/
That's about it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post helpful, but the code line below did not work:

```
    var dueDate = $(this).val();
```

Instead I used the code below and it worked

```
    var dueDate = $(this).text();
```